# MySQL invalid settings - Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=%Id

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

UPDATED 6-1-2021

A fresh installation of xampp with the same version solved the problem.
To avoid loosing old database I moved the folder of the db (located in xampp/mysql/data/dbName) into the same location in the xampp new installation.

When I tried to access MySQL from xampp I got this error,
MySQL said: Documentation

```
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
```

```
> Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=%Id 
> mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet.PID=32452 
> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away 
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed. 
> Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=%Id 
> mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=32452
> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away 
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
> rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
> password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
> the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

After searching a bit here's some of the things I tried to do

1- changing max_allowed_packet in my.ini to 2G then restarting mySQL

2- Accessing phpmyadmin from localhost without the port number (like this: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/)

3- Checked if there's another app running on port 3306

4- Created my.cnf file following this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/strategicsm/10.0.2?topic=ccmd-creating-configuring-mycnf-file-windows-machines-1 tutorial in xampp/mysql/bin
and set max_connections=4096 and max_allowed_packet=2G

Comment: How did you get this error ? Reaching `localhost:3306` from your browser ?

Comment: yes by going to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Then no. I don't know what's the problem here but I remember that this error could appear if you try to reach MySQL through HTTP (as you shouldn't do it).

Comment: XAMPP generally comes with workable `my.cnf` settings out-of-the-box. You shouldn't have to fiddle with them. 4096 connections is absurdly large for a desktop. (If you're running that IBM software product ask IBM for help; heaven knows you're paying for it.)  Your error message says the MySQL server crashed while you were trying to connect. Try downloading another client program, like [HeidiSQL](https://heidisql.com) and connecting that way.